# Possibly faulty logic re badges

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

If I look at my profile/activity on this site, it tells me that the next "badge" I can earn is "Commentator".

If I click on this it says "How do you earn this badge?   Leave 10 comments".

However, I cannot leave comments as my rep is < 50.   So I cannot earn this badge eh?

Comment: [Your SO comment total is currently 7](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5656369/john?tab=activity&sort=comments)

Comment: Related bug: I am completely unable to posts comments.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett Your problem would seem to warrant a separate post, if you cannot post comments at all...

Comment: @John  Jean is joking... :-)

Comment: @John: ^^^ this ^^^^

Answer (score 10):

You can leave comments with less than 50 rep, they just have to be on your own posts. So you absolutely can earn this badge right now.

You can always choose a different badge by clicking on the cog icon.

Comment: I completely forgot that was even possible.

Answer (score 3):

This is working as intended.

Badges don't get disabled based on whether or not you can make progress on them (In fact, they don't get disabled at all).
You just need to earn that first 50 rep, or comment on your own posts as [Robert Longson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson) [suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320801/1835379), to start "working" on this badge.